# Product Key for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, product-key

Hello can anyone tell me about the windows product key
I have brought a dvd to install windows 7 please tell me where is the product key written there is a barcode written in its cover is that the product or it is written some where else and please tell me  about the disks how to carry them in between installation

Comment: Is it a genuine Windows DVD?

Comment: If what you purchased is actually genuine there will be a sticker with the product key.  If there isn't a sticker on the cardboard envelope it came in then it isn't genuine.

Answer (score 0):

The product key should be printed on a sticker located somewhere on the DVD box.

Product keys are of the 5x5 set (25-character) form as in xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx

> please tell me about the disks how to carry them in between installation

The installation wizard will ask for the production key during the installation. Also, you are able to apply the product key after the installation by using the command slmgr /ipk